# jQuery data() JSON Encoding issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my current jQuery Mobile application I trap click events on a variety of HTML elements, extract the whole set of data-* attributes for the element using

```
var data = $(element).data();
```

package it all into JSON string

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and send it off elsewhere for downstream processing.

The problem I have run into (and I am pretty sure it has only started with the recent versions of jQuery Mobile) is with some elements such as radios, checkboxes and buttons which have annonymous functions as part of the data() array. Serializing such functions is

- not relevent to my application
- more importantly, triggers a JavaScript along the lines of "An attempt was made to use an object that is no longer valid"...

By dint of some experiment I have found that the issue is to do with anonymous functions that turn up in the raw data() object as

1. buttonElements
2. mobile-checkboxradio

etc.  I then build my own object to serialize that is devoid of these offending entities.

This is OK but I have found another issue.  Change the jQM version and BOOM, the problem crops up all over again since the attribute name has changed (e.g. mobileCheckboxRadio in place of mobile-checkboxradio).

Question - could anyone suggest a more generic, attribute name agnostic, way of stripping out these offensive bits?  My own efforts and trying to figure out the typeof of the object attribute have failed since what I get is always a string.  I suppose I could always check for the phrase "annonymous function" in that string but that sounds clumsy.

Comment: I don't think the data function is intended to be used like that, why do you need all the DOM attributes transferred?

Comment: Calling .data() with no parameters retrieves all of the values as a JavaScript object. - I quote from [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: From what i understand it should be used to get specific data from DOM elements, why do you need all the DOM attributes transferred to a remote server? if you answer i could maybe come up with a more valid way of doing what you need

Comment: I did not answer your question because it really is not too relevant.  However, to give you the context it is like this - the click events occur inside a document being rendered in an iframe.  I pick up the full load of data-* attributes there, JSON stringify them and pass them to another application via PostMessage which then does a load of weird and wonderful things with those data.  The data are not being passed back to the server.

Comment: p.s. - as my link to the documentation indicates I do not believe that my way of accessing all data-* attributes is "invalid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.  One can do the following

```
var data = $(element).data();
$.each(data,function(key,prop){if ('object' != typeof(prop)) /*do something */)}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKGQ5/4/) demonstrating what happens with a radio button.  As you will note two of the data-* attributes returned are objects.  One of them, mobileCheckboxradio is an anonymous function.  Try to serialize data as is and you get an exception - which is being trapped and reported.  With the safely cloned object, which is shorn of the anon function all goes well.

This has the benefit of being "version proof".  Whether it is better than simply checking for the small handful of attributes that are liable to cause such errors is debatable.